# Is it possible to pass @Input object to a component using content projection in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-content-projection

I want to do something like this in app.component:

```
<app-table-container [data]="tableData">
  <app-some-table></app-some-table>
</app-table-container>
```

table-container.component.html

```
<!-- stuff that also needs data-object -->
<ng-content [data]="data"></ng-content>
```

table-container.component.ts

```
@Input() data: ITableStuff;
```

some-table.component.ts

```
@Input() data: ITableStuff;
```

This doesn't work

I can pass the tableData to both in app.component but I'd like to pass it only to table-container and from there to projected content.

Comment: Why do you want to do such a thing ? The easy way is, as you suggested, providing data to both components in your `app.component.html`. Or not using content projection, where you'd use `<app-some-table>` inside `table-container.component.html`.

Comment: Why not simply inject the `AppSomeTableContainer` in the `AppSomeTable` and read the `container.data` from there? Easy...

Comment: @Pieterjan: Thanks. I haven't injected a parent component to the child. Actually i didn't know you can do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can "reach" the parent using in constructor of app-some-table and use a getter (not an input)

```
get data()
{
   return this.tableComponent?this.tableComponent.data:null
}
constructor(@Host() @Optional() private tableComponent:AppTableComponent){}
```

You can also, instead use a getter assign the value in ngAfterViewOnInit

```
export class ChildComponent implements AfterViewInit{
  data!:any
  constructor(@Host() @Optional() private tableComponent:ParentComponent){}
  ngAfterViewInit()
  {
    this.data=this.tableComponent?this.tableComponent.data:null
  }
}
```

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-rwhvn1?file=src%2Fmain.ts) (in the stackblitz is the second option, I enclosed in a setTimeout when equal the data to avoid the error "Expression has changed after it was checked")

**Update** another approach is use ContentChild.

In our parent

```
 @ContentChild(ChildComponent) child!:ChildComponent
```

And in ngAfterViewInit

```
  ngAfterViewInit()
  {
    setTimeout(()=>{
      if (this.child)
        this.child.anotherData=this.data
    })
  }
```

But this approach need know the "childComponent" class. Always can extends all the possibles child from a component base and ask about "ChildComponentBase"

Comment: Thanks! I didn't explain my situation properly and I don't want the table to assume anything about it's parent. However I'll try this solution also.

Comment: @charm, I added another approach, but it's possible it's not what you're looking for :(

Comment: The contentchild-approach is exactly what i need but i can't get it to work

Comment: @charm, I just update the stackblitz adding a new property "anotherData" to the child

Comment: I created better question from your suggestion. Please have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76588220/how-to-use-contentchild-with-ng-content-without-specifying-the-exact-class-of-th

Answer (score 0):

It is not straightforward because of DI hierarchy in this case.

One option is to use `ContentChild`/`ContentChildren` to get instance of some-table.component and assign its input in `AfterContentInit` callback.

Comment: This sounds like the real solution. TableContainerComponent will be a component used in multiple places and it always has a table component as a child that needs the data.

Comment: Please have a look at my new, better question based on ContentChild suggestion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76588220/how-to-use-contentchild-with-ng-content-without-specifying-the-exact-class-of-th