# How to use ContentChild with ng-content without specifying the exact class of the content projected component?

Tags: angular, angular2-ngcontent

I'm trying to create a general purpose container component for all tables so they all have same headers (possible buttons, filter-chips, search-field). I'm planning to use content projection with ng-content and passing data to the table using ContentChild. But this scenario works ONLY if the ContentChild is given the exact class of the component and not the base class. So I can't make it a general purpose container component that can be given any table component that extends the base class.

So I have

component-one.html

```
<app-table-container [data]="tableData">
  <app-some-table></app-some-table>
</app-table-container>
```

table-container.component.html

```
<!-- here above the content projected table would be common
 stuff for all tables -->
<ng-content select="[tableComponent]"></ng-content>
```

table-container.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-table-container',
  templateUrl: './table-container.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./table-container.component.scss']
})
export class TableContainerComponent implements AfterContentInit {
  @Input() data: ITableStuff;
  @ContentChild(TableBaseComponent) tableComponent: TableBaseComponent;
  
  ngAfterContentInit(): void {
    // below fails because this.tableComponent is undefined
    this.tableComponent.data = this.data;
  }
}
```

table-base.component.ts

```
@Component({
  template: ''
})
export class TableBaseComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @Input() data: ITableStuff;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    console.log(this.data.name);
  }
}
```

some-table.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-some-table',
  template: '<p>some-table works!</p>'
})
export class SomeTableComponent extends TableBaseComponent implements {
  
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
}
```

However in TableContainerComponent.ngAfterContentInit the this.tableComponent is undefined. If I have:

```
@ContentChild(SomeTableComponent) tableComponent: SomeTableComponent;
```

it works. But then there's nothing general purpose in my container component.

Comment: This currently a limitation of content projection in angular. See https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/37319

Comment: Thanks for info. Any ideas how to implement TableContainerComponent? interested in any mechanism that works. I can naturally pass the data to both container and the table but I'd like it to do it more neat.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create interface `ISomeInterface` and `InjectionToken<ISomeInterface>`:

```
export interface ISomeInterface { data: string[] }

export const mytoken = new InjectionToken<ISomeInterface>('ISomeInterface');
```

Make each table-like component implement interface and provide itself as `InjectionToken<ISomeInterface>`:

```
@Component({
    providers: [{provide: mytoken, useExisting: forwardRef(() => TableComponent)}]
})
export class TableComponent implements ISomeInterface {
    @Input()
    data: string[];
}
```

and then use it in `ContentChild(mytoken)`:

```
@ContentChild(mytoken) tableComponent: ISomeInterface;
```

Instead of token you can use custom base class.

Comment: Now I got it, your answer skips the TableBaseComponent. I got passing the data to work, but still can't see the content of the content projected component (in your answer TableComponent, in my question SomeTableComponent). Have to dig into this a bit.

Comment: To clarify. The SomeTableComponent is created. It writes in console.log the data. But the default html (some table works!) is not displayed. Developer tools -> Elements also doesn't show it.